# How to do infinite attempts in Bull Queue?

Tags: node.js, queue, message-queue, job-queue, bull.js

I am trying to send a user email after he registeres on my website

My current code looks like this

```
const data = {
      from: 'no-reply@test.com',
      to: req.user.email,
      subject: 'Please reset your Test Account Password',
      text:
        'This is a test email to ask you to reset your Test Account Password. Good luck :)',
    }
    const options = {
      attempts: 1000,
      backoff: { type: 'exponential', delay: 30000 },
      removeOnComplete: true,
    }
    sendMailQueue.add('resetEmail', data, options)
```

How do I set the attempts to INFINITE?

Comment: If you're trying to send an email message you can have multiple issue:
 - email availability (mailbox full, etc.)
 - spam filter
 - destination smtp availability 

So I would say that is not realistic

Comment: @hpfs so if a user registers and for some reason your email fails 5 times then what to do? not confirm the user at all?

Comment: It depends on your policy. What if the user gave you a wrong email address? Or just made a typo? Or the provider of his/her email is failing?

My opinion you can have two approach:
1. let the user in and show a banner that he/she is not yet verified and give change password ability.
2. ignore the probblem the user will register again

Comment: what would be those 2 approaches if you dont mind sharing?

Comment: sorry just hit enter :)

Comment: My opinion you can have two approach: 1. let the user in and show a banner that he/she is not yet verified and give change password ability. 2. ignore the probblem the user will register again

Answer (score 1):

In producer, set attempts while creating new task

```
const taskOpts = {
    attempts: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
}

Client.add(taskType, taskData, taskOpts)
```